# Advise how to fix the error (xelatex)

Tags: xetex

I tried with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}%
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Path = ./Fonts/ ,
UprightFont= TimesNewRomPSPro,
BoldFont= TimesNewRomPSPro-Bol,
ItalicFont=TimesNewRomPSPro-Ita,
BoldItalicFont=TimesNewRomPSPro-BolIta,
]{TimesNewRomPSPro}%
\setmathfont[]{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{latin,Latin,num}]{TimesNewRomPSPro}


\begin{document}
sin $\sin x=y$ \textit{x} $\displaystyle\frac{d \hat{t}}{d s}$
\end{document}
```

It produced errors, and I'm not aware how to fix it, note that if I comment the command `\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{latin,Latin,num}]{TimesNewRomPSPro}` then it works fine, but I kept this command because of I need to get the `arabic` and `alpha numerals` in `Math` also into `TimesNewRoman` font, please suggest what I did wrong....

XeLaTeX just got hanged when I run the file, and the screenshot is:

[image]

Much thanks for your valuable suggestions....

As `David Carlisle` suggested, I've waited a while and got the error and the `log` file is

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (MiKTeX 21.3) (preloaded format=xelatex 2022.1.5)  15 FEB 2022 22:40
entering extended mode
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count175
\c@section=\count176
\c@subsection=\count177
\c@subsubsection=\count178
\c@paragraph=\count179
\c@subparagraph=\count180
\c@figure=\count181
\c@table=\count182
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/unicode-math\unicode-math.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2021-02-18 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xetex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2021-03-18 L3 backend support: XeTeX
 ()
\c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int=\count183
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count184
\g__color_backend_stack_int=\count185
\g__graphics_track_int=\count186
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box47
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count187
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count188
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count189
))
Package: unicode-math 2020/01/31 v0.8q Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/unicode-math\unicode-math-xetex.sty
Package: unicode-math-xetex 2020/01/31 v0.8q Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLa
TeX

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse-2020-10-01.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse-generic.tex)))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e\l3keys2e.sty
Package: l3keys2e 2021-03-12 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.sty
Package: fontspec 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count190
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count191
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count192
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count193
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count194
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count195
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count196
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count197
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count198
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count199
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count266
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen139
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen140
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen141

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.cfg)))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fix-cm.sty
Package: fix-cm 2015/01/14 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ts1enc.def
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding TS1 on input line 47.
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2020/09/23 v2.17i AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip49

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks15
\ex@=\dimen142
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen143
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count267
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count268
\leftroot@=\count269
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count270
\DOTSCASE@=\count271
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box48
\strutbox@=\box49
\big@size=\dimen144
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count272
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count273
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count274
\dspbrk@lvl=\count275
\tag@help=\toks16
\row@=\count276
\column@=\count277
\maxfields@=\count278
\andhelp@=\toks17
\eqnshift@=\dimen145
\alignsep@=\dimen146
\tagshift@=\dimen147
\tagwidth@=\dimen148
\totwidth@=\dimen149
\lineht@=\dimen150
\@envbody=\toks18
\multlinegap=\skip50
\multlinetaggap=\skip51
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks19
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
)
\g__um_fam_int=\count279
\g__um_fonts_used_int=\count280
\l__um_primecount_int=\count281
\g__um_primekern_muskip=\muskip17

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/unicode-math\unicode-math-table.tex)))

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'TimesNewRomPSPro(0)' created for font
(fontspec)             'TimesNewRomPSPro' with options
(fontspec)             [Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=tex-text,Path =
(fontspec)             ./Fonts/,UprightFont= TimesNewRomPSPro,BoldFont=
(fontspec)             TimesNewRomPSPro-Bol,ItalicFont=TimesNewRomPSPro-Ita,Bol
dItalicFont=TimesNewRomPSPro-BolIta].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[./Fonts/TimesNewRomPSPro]/OT:script=latn;language=d
flt;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[./Fonts/TimesNewRomPSPro]/OT:script=latn;language=d
flt;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[./Fonts/TimesNewRomPSPro-Bol]/OT:script=latn;langua
ge=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[./Fonts/TimesNewRomPSPro-Ita]/OT:script=latn;langua
ge=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[./Fonts/TimesNewRomPSPro-BolIta]/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.: 


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'TimesNewRomPSPro(1)' created for font
(fontspec)             'TimesNewRomPSPro' with options [Mapping=tex-text,Path
(fontspec)             = ./Fonts/,UprightFont= TimesNewRomPSPro,BoldFont=
(fontspec)             TimesNewRomPSPro-Bol,ItalicFont=TimesNewRomPSPro-Ita,Bol
dItalicFont=TimesNewRomPSPro-BolIta].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[./Fonts/TimesNewRomPSPro]/OT:script=latn;language=d
flt;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[./Fonts/TimesNewRomPSPro]/OT:script=latn;language=d
flt;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[./Fonts/TimesNewRomPSPro-Bol]/OT:script=latn;langua
ge=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[./Fonts/TimesNewRomPSPro-Ita]/OT:script=latn;langua
ge=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[./Fonts/TimesNewRomPSPro-BolIta]/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.: 

LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/TimesNewRomPSPro(1)/m/n on input lin
e 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/TimesNewRomPSPro(1)/m/it on input l
ine 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/TimesNewRomPSPro(1)/b/n on input li
ne 10.

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'latinmodern-math.otf(0)' created for font
(fontspec)             'latinmodern-math.otf' with options
(fontspec)             [BoldItalicFont={},ItalicFont={},SmallCapsFont={},Script
=Math].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:script=math;language=dflt;
"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'latinmodern-math.otf(1)' created for font
(fontspec)             'latinmodern-math.otf' with options
(fontspec)             [BoldItalicFont={},ItalicFont={},SmallCapsFont={},Script
=Math,SizeFeatures={{Size=8.5-},{Size=6-8.5,Font=latinmodern-math.otf,Style=Mat
hScript},{Size=-6,Font=latinmodern-math.otf,Style=MathScriptScript}}].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <8.5->"[latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:script=math;language=df
lt;"<6-8.5>"[latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:script=math;language=dflt;+ssty=0;"<-6>"[
latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:script=math;language=dflt;+ssty=1;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 

LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n on input
 line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/b/n on inpu
t line 11.

Package fontspec Info: latinmodern-math scale = 1.0001.


Package fontspec Info: latinmodern-math scale = 1.0001.


Package fontspec Info: latinmodern-math scale = 1.0001.


Package fontspec Info: latinmodern-math scale = 1.0001.


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'latinmodern-math.otf(2)' created for font
(fontspec)             'latinmodern-math.otf' with options
(fontspec)             [BoldItalicFont={},ItalicFont={},SmallCapsFont={},Script
=Math,SizeFeatures={{Size=8.5-},{Size=6-8.5,Font=latinmodern-math.otf,Style=Mat
hScript},{Size=-6,Font=latinmodern-math.otf,Style=MathScriptScript}},ScaleAgain
=1.0001,FontAdjustment={\fontdimen
(fontspec)             8\font =6.77pt\relax \fontdimen 9\font =3.94pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 10\font =4.44pt\relax \fontdimen 11\font
(fontspec)             =6.86pt\relax \fontdimen 12\font =3.45pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 13\font =3.63pt\relax \fontdimen 14\font
(fontspec)             =3.63pt\relax \fontdimen 15\font =2.89pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 16\font =2.47pt\relax \fontdimen 17\font
(fontspec)             =2.47pt\relax \fontdimen 18\font =2.5pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 19\font =2.0pt\relax \fontdimen 22\font
(fontspec)             =2.5pt\relax \fontdimen 20\font =0pt\relax \fontdimen
(fontspec)             21\font =0pt\relax }].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <8.5->s*[1.0001]"[latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:script=math;l
anguage=dflt;"<6-8.5>s*[1.0001]"[latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:script=math;language=
dflt;+ssty=0;"<-6>s*[1.0001]"[latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:script=math;language=dfl
t;+ssty=1;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 8\font =6.77pt\relax \fontdimen 9\font
(fontspec)             =3.94pt\relax \fontdimen 10\font =4.44pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 11\font =6.86pt\relax \fontdimen 12\font
(fontspec)             =3.45pt\relax \fontdimen 13\font =3.63pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 14\font =3.63pt\relax \fontdimen 15\font
(fontspec)             =2.89pt\relax \fontdimen 16\font =2.47pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 17\font =2.47pt\relax \fontdimen 18\font
(fontspec)             =2.5pt\relax \fontdimen 19\font =2.0pt\relax \fontdimen
(fontspec)             22\font =2.5pt\relax \fontdimen 20\font =0pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 21\font =0pt\relax 

LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMS' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `symbols' in the math version `normal' on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> TU/latinmodern-math.otf(2)/m/n on inpu
t line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMS' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `symbols' in the math version `bold' on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> TU/latinmodern-math.otf(2)/b/n on inpu
t line 11.

Package fontspec Info: latinmodern-math scale = 0.9999.


Package fontspec Info: latinmodern-math scale = 0.9999.


Package fontspec Info: latinmodern-math scale = 0.9999.


Package fontspec Info: latinmodern-math scale = 0.9999.


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'latinmodern-math.otf(3)' created for font
(fontspec)             'latinmodern-math.otf' with options
(fontspec)             [BoldItalicFont={},ItalicFont={},SmallCapsFont={},Script
=Math,SizeFeatures={{Size=8.5-},{Size=6-8.5,Font=latinmodern-math.otf,Style=Mat
hScript},{Size=-6,Font=latinmodern-math.otf,Style=MathScriptScript}},ScaleAgain
=0.9999,FontAdjustment={\fontdimen
(fontspec)             8\font =0.4pt\relax \fontdimen 9\font =2.0pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 10\font =1.67pt\relax \fontdimen 11\font
(fontspec)             =1.11pt\relax \fontdimen 12\font =6.0pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 13\font =0pt\relax }].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <8.5->s*[0.9999]"[latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:script=math;l
anguage=dflt;"<6-8.5>s*[0.9999]"[latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:script=math;language=
dflt;+ssty=0;"<-6>s*[0.9999]"[latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:script=math;language=dfl
t;+ssty=1;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 8\font =0.4pt\relax \fontdimen 9\font
(fontspec)             =2.0pt\relax \fontdimen 10\font =1.67pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 11\font =1.11pt\relax \fontdimen 12\font
(fontspec)             =6.0pt\relax \fontdimen 13\font =0pt\relax 

LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `normal' on input line 1
1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> TU/latinmodern-math.otf(3)/m/n on inpu
t line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `bold' on input line 11.

LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> TU/latinmodern-math.otf(3)/b/n on inpu
t line 11.


! Package fontspec Error: The font "TimesNewRomPSPro" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.12 
     
? x
 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 7099 strings out of 411686
 153068 string characters out of 2840104
 653454 words of memory out of 3000000
 27106 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 403762 words of font info for 40 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 98i,0n,116p,302b,2768s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

Fonts are available at: https://easyupload.io/m/frodvl

Comment: if you want help with an error it helps if you say what error you got, (copy from the log file into a code block so line endings are preserved)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Error screenshot added, thanks for pointing...

Comment: a text block is more useful than a screenshot, and there is no error shown in the screenshot that you posted, xelatex pauses reading the math table but should carry on after a while.

Comment: I don't have the font so at that point I get `! Package fontspec Error: The font "TimesNewRomPSPro" cannot be found` if you have the font it should work but may take a while the first time as it may have to remake the font cache

Comment: @DavidCarlisle xetex does not remake the font cache. Maybe, the font TimesNewRomPSPro is bad. But I don't have it, I cannot try it.

Comment: @wipet in windows/miktex xetex will trigger a fc-cache if it can't find the font.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle as you suggested, got the error after waiting some time...and the error was posted

Comment: that's a bit odd: you get the error I get (but I haven't got the font) but you appear to have loaded the font earlier... it works without error if you just load it for text?

Comment: what happens if you try lualatex?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, LuaLaTeX produced the output, but the math is in different font, meantime, I'll try to upload the font somewhere ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and `wipet, fonts are uploaded to https://easyupload.io/m/frodvl Please download it

Comment: sorry unless that font has an open licence I will not download

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry to ask, `open licence` means???

Comment: the font is available for purchase for £65 from https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/times-new-roman-ps/pro-regular/?refby=whatfontis  do you have a version that has a licence that allows distribution?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry to interrupt, I've checked the fonts provided by the `OP`, it looks like he/she already purchased....excuse if my guess is wrong...

Comment: @MadyYuvi that is not what you asked. More to the point, you now have the font on your machine, have you paid for a licence? I did not download as I have not seen a free licence that would allow me to do so.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, understood....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry for the late reply, I understood the concern, you can replace the default font of `Times New Roman` (hope this was available by default) instead of `TimesNewRomanPsPro`, my concern is I need the same font both in text and math...Thanks...

Comment: @GowriSaro I tried chaning to a public font earlier but gave up as you are explicitly listing all the variants and I didn't want to guess what would be equivalent. If you edit the question  to show the problem with Times New Roman or better TeX Gyre Termes (asthat is in tex distributions) then we can look again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}%
\usepackage[]{newtxmath} % For testing purposes.
\usepackage{mathspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Path = ./Fonts/ ,
UprightFont= TimesNewRomPSPro,
BoldFont= TimesNewRomPSPro-Bol,
ItalicFont=TimesNewRomPSPro-Ita,
BoldItalicFont=TimesNewRomPSPro-BolIta,
]{TimesNewRomPSPro}%

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"39}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
-- --- fi fl ffi ffl \quad sin \textit{d} 
\end{document}
```

This is works fine with me, hope some experts will advise if this is correct...